# How to select or retrieve only specific fields after elasticsearch query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, filter, get, pyelasticsearch

I am able to query an index in elasticsearch. And, now I want to narrow down the data to some specific fields. But, I am keep getting errors.

**Here is my query:**

```py
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="myhost", "port":0000)


search_body={
    "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {"exists": {"field": "customer_name"}},
                {"match_phrase": {"city": "chicago"}},
                ]
        }

    }

results = es.search(index="some_index", query=search_body)
```

I am easily able to get results upto this point. But, since the returned has so many fields, I want to retrieve only specific fields before converting it into a dataframe. I can convert it into a dataframe and then filter, but that is not optimal.

I tried adding `_source` and `field` methods as:

```py
search_body={
    "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {"exists": {"field": "customer_name"}},
                {"match_phrase": {"city": "chicago"}},
                ]
        },
    "_source":{"fields": {"includes":["customer_name", "city", "company", "company_address"] }}
    }
```

and other variants like,

```py
"fields": {"includes":["customer_name", "city", "company", "company_address"] }

# or 

"_source":{"includes":["customer_name", "city", "company", "company_address"] }

# and several others.
```

I keep getting error:

```
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]')
```

I followed:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering
- several stackoverflow answers
- even tried named query

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is with passing the "search_body" parameters as `body` or `query`.

If my "search_body" is as given below, I cannot pass it as `query` because query is meant to be a specific "query" I request on the indexes. Requesting `_source` on this query malforms the request.

```py
search_body={
    "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {"exists": {"field": "customer_name"}},
                {"match_phrase": {"city": "chicago"}},
                ]
        },
    "_source":{"fields": {"includes":["customer_name", "city", "company", "company_address"] }}
    }
```

This will pass because the request is actually passed as body, which contains the "query" and another "_source" field to subset the data.

```py
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="myhost", "port":0000)

results = es.search(index="some_index", body=search_body)
```

This will fail because I have requested the search as query and again asking for subsetting the data.

```py
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="myhost", "port":0000)

results = es.search(index="some_index", query=search_body)
```

This second request will pass if our `search_body` is as:

```py
search_body={
    "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {"exists": {"field": "customer_name"}},
                {"match_phrase": {"city": "chicago"}},
                ]
        }
    }
```

but for naming convention the key should be named "query_body".

```py
query_body={
    "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {"exists": {"field": "customer_name"}},
                {"match_phrase": {"city": "chicago"}},
                ]
        }
    }
```

and requested as:

```py
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="myhost", "port":0000)

results = es.search(index="some_index", query=query_body)
```

So, it is to be understood that `query` and `body` are two different ways of requesting data on a index.

Note: Python elasticsearch client may be soon deprecating the `body` argument in its request. In that case let's see how we can subset the filtered/queried data.

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from the JSON you provided your `_source` field is landing inside your `bool` query. Instead you should have it structured like so:

```py
search_body = {
  "query": {
    "bool": [
      {...}
    ]
   },
   "_source": {
     "includes": [...]
   }
}
```

(disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the Python Elasticsearch client and work for Elastic)

Comment: I did try that, and it does not work. Whenever I put `"query":{"bool": .... }` I get query malformed error. If it was Kibana search it could work but it's not work for pyelasticsearch client. 
Since "search_body" itself is a query, extra "query" parameter does not matter. I would assume so because it has never worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
results = es.search(index="some_index", query=search_body, source_includes=[...])
```

[Code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/ff5152fa884b7576e8028615e2c94149bc09477a/elasticsearch/_sync/client/__init__.py#L2915) is the best documentation (sometimes!)

Comment: A shame this is not available in OpenSearch (yet?)!

Comment: Oh - it's there - just with a leading underscore rather `_source_includes=[...]`